# Query to find the most played enemy

Tags: mysql, sql

I've realized some sort of online game. Now I'd like do show a statistic where you can see who was the enemy you played most against.

I've stored the games in a database. The players are stored in the fields PLAYER1 and PLAYER2. It depends, which one invites the other one. The one who starts the game and invites the other one is PLAYER1.

```
ID | PLAYER1 | PLAYER2 | GAMESTATE
```

Now I have certain entries. Let's guess I am player 1 and my friend (2) invited me twice, also I invited him once. The Entries would look as follows:

```
1  | 2       | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 1       | 1
3  | 1       | 2       | 1
4  | 3       | 4       | 1  <-- some other random game
```

Now, I'd like to know the player I have played most with. I actually need one select which counts the most played player, but in both cases (PLAYER1 or PLAYER2).

What would be the best solution for one single query? May I use [`MySQL UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/union.html) or GROUP BY? If yes, how do I have to do?

**EDIT**: Expected result would actually be this:

```
PLAYER | MOST_ENEMY | GAMES
1      | 2          | 3
2      | 1          | 3
3      | 4          | 1
4      | 3          | 1
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      PLAYER1,
      PLAYER2,
      COUNT(*) CNT
    FROM
      (
        SELECT PLAYER1, PLAYER2 FROM matches 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT PLAYER2 PLAYER1, PLAYER1 PLAYER2 FROM matches
      ) sub
    GROUP BY
      sub.PLAYER1,
      sub.PLAYER2
    ) sub2
GROUP BY
  sub2.PLAYER1
HAVING
  sub2.CNT = MAX(sub2.CNT)
```

Comment: Actually I get the sum of games with every enemy of me. See my edited question for more detail about the expected result.

Comment: What would you expect if you have another result for player 1 which is not with player 2? Like this line: `5, 1, 3, 1` in your entry table?

Comment: But there are still the sums of all matches... Now I'd like from this result to get only those who are the biggest. I tried surrounding it as follows:
`SELECT PLAYER1, PLAYER2, MAX(CNT) FROM (yourquery) GROUP BY PLAYER1`, but this result was not correct...

Comment: I also have edited the query, this one works perfectly for me:

`SELECT x.PLAYER1, x.PLAYER2, MAX(x.CNT)
FROM
(SELECT 
  PLAYER1,
  PLAYER2,
  COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM
  (
    SELECT PLAYER1, PLAYER2 FROM MULTIPLAYERVERSUS
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PLAYER2 PLAYER1, PLAYER1 PLAYER2 FROM MULTIPLAYERVERSUS
  ) sub
WHERE sub.PLAYER1 != 0
AND sub.PLAYER2 != 0
GROUP BY
  sub.PLAYER1,
  sub.PLAYER2
ORDER BY CNT DESC
) x
GROUP BY PLAYER1`

This works, but I forgot the order by at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are player 1...

```
select 
    case player1 when 1 then player2 else player1 end as player, 
    count(*) as games
from yourtable
where 1 in (player1, player2)
group by case player1 when 1 then player2 else player1 end 
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

To find the general cases, it's more complex - you're into groupwise maximums, etc

```
create temporary table games (id int, player int)
insert games (id,player)
    select ID, PLAYER1 as player
    from yourtable
    union
    select ID, PLAYER2
    from yourtable

create temporary table gamecount (player1 int, player2 int, gamecount int)
insert gamecount (player1,player2,gamecount)
    select c1.player, c2.player as player2, COUNT(*) as gamecount
        from games c1
        inner join games c2
           on c1.ID = c2.id
           and c1.player<>c2.player

    group by c1.player, c2.player

select * from gamecount topscore
where not exists
(select * from gamecount high 
where high.player1 = topscore.player1 
and high.gamecount>topscore.gamecount)
order by player1, gamecount desc


drop temporary table gamecount
drop temporary table games
```

Comment: This query does actually work for me! But I'd like to have one query for all users, not one query per user :/ you may see my edited question

Comment: Ah, now that's a different question, made more so by your choice of platform and it's lack of Ranking and Common Table Expresssions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when player1< player2 then player1 else player2 end) first_player, 
(case when player1 > player2 then player1 else player2 end) second_player, 
count(*) games
 from game
where (player1 = 1 or player2 = 1) 
group by first_player, second_player
order by games desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This query does actually work for me! But I'd like to have one query for all users, not one query per user :/ you may see my edited question